# Продолжительное время подключения к РБД MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, .net-core

При использовании официального пакета, для работы с MySql, из NuGet. Возникает следующая проблема:

**Опробовано на двух серверах. Под Ubuntu и Fedora. Разницы никакой.

Время выполнения одной строчки кода:

con.Open();

1) Если приложение Windows Forms App(.NET Framework) время подключения бывает меньше 1 миллисекунды.

На красный на картинках не обращайте внимания

[image: скриншот скорости нескольких подключений.]

2) Если приложение Console App(.NET Framework), то скорость около 60 миллисекунд.

[image: скриншот скорости нескольких подключений.]

3) Если приложение Console App(.NET Core), то скорость около 200 миллисекунд, а в праздники может доходить до 3 секунд!

[image: скриншот скорости нескольких подключений.]

```
            using (var con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;

                con.Open();

                DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine((t2 - t1).TotalMilliseconds);

                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = "select now()";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Пожалуйста, пожалуйста объясните мне почему и как это исправить?

Comment: А покажите-ка полный код для каждого из случаев, наверняка есть отличия, которые вы считаете несущественными, а они то как раз и оказывают влияние.

Comment: @Bulson,   Конечно, во всех трех случаях один и тот же, просто один раз запускается с помощью mono, а второй и третий просто скомпилированы под непосредственно систему. Добавил в вопрос